# Is there a tool that will allow me to develop an app for Windows, Mac, iOS and Android?

Tags: windows, android, software-development, osx, ios

An app I want to develop should run on all four platforms - Windows, Mac, iOS and Android. It's mostly text-based, with tables, buttons, etc.

I've seen tools for develop apps that run on Windows and Macs, and ones for iOS and Android, but nothing for all four. Maybe I'm asking for the impossible?

I want to write the app for all four with as much common code as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/) supports cross-platform app development across Windows (UWP), [macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/), iOS, and Android, claiming 90% code reuse. [Xamarin.Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/), which is designed for basic form-like apps, has significantly higher code reuse, but only supports Windows, iOS, and Android.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look at Xamarin.

Comment: You should also look into [Flutter/Dart](https://flutter.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend [Embarcadero RAD Studio](https://www.embarcadero.com/) (if you can code either C++ or Pascal (even if not, it would be worth learning, just to use this excellent app)).

> Build once and deploy modern apps for every platform - FAST

With a drag & drop GUI builder and hundreds, probably thousands of 3rd party components, you write your code once and build it for Windows, macOS, iOS, Android and Linux.

The downside is the cost - over $1k - but, it is free to use the full version until you generate over $5k using it, so that ought not to be a problem.

It is very full-featured, having matured over 20 years, with great refactoring, and excellent debugger & everything else you could desire.
I find that I am incredibly productive when using it. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know C++, but I know C#, and my revenue will likely be under $5k.

Comment: If you know C#, you should have no trouble with C++ (and Pascal is even easier to learn).  This is a ***very*** powerful IDE. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks, I certainly will give it a try. I remember learning a little Pascal way back in the 70's, but I didn't know it was still alive.

Comment: Lolx! Yes, it is still (barely) alive. There is an excellent free cross platform IDE at https://www.lazarus-ide.org/ BUt, much as I love FOSS, the Embracdero (used to be Borland - remember them?) IDE is far superior